# bazel build :protoc :protobuf failed

Tags: protocol-buffers

```
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
DEBUG: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_wang/181be6b67ee4902db879f2b646f0f657/external/rules_jvm_external/coursier.bzl:445:22: The inputs to maven_install.json have changed, but the lock file has not been regenerated. Consider running 'bazel run @unpinned_maven//:pin'
ERROR: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_wang/181be6b67ee4902db879f2b646f0f657/external/rules_pkg/pkg/mappings.bzl:108:12: name 'json' is not defined
ERROR: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_wang/181be6b67ee4902db879f2b646f0f657/external/rules_pkg/pkg/mappings.bzl:224:22: name 'json' is not defined
ERROR: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_wang/181be6b67ee4902db879f2b646f0f657/external/rules_pkg/pkg/mappings.bzl:413:22: name 'json' is not defined
ERROR: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_wang/181be6b67ee4902db879f2b646f0f657/external/rules_pkg/pkg/mappings.bzl:473:22: name 'json' is not defined
INFO: Repository rules_proto instantiated at:
  /home/wang/test_csh/protobuf-21.5/WORKSPACE:31:14: in <toplevel>
  /home/wang/test_csh/protobuf-21.5/protobuf_deps.bzl:73:24: in protobuf_deps
  /home/wang/test_csh/protobuf-21.5/protobuf_deps.bzl:19:17: in _github_archive
Repository rule http_archive defined at:
  /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_wang/181be6b67ee4902db879f2b646f0f657/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:336:31: in <toplevel>
INFO: Repository rules_cc instantiated at:
  /home/wang/test_csh/protobuf-21.5/WORKSPACE:31:14: in <toplevel>
  /home/wang/test_csh/protobuf-21.5/protobuf_deps.bzl:57:24: in protobuf_deps
  /home/wang/test_csh/protobuf-21.5/protobuf_deps.bzl:19:17: in _github_archive
Repository rule http_archive defined at:
  /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_wang/181be6b67ee4902db879f2b646f0f657/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:336:31: in <toplevel>
INFO: Repository rules_java instantiated at:
  /home/wang/test_csh/protobuf-21.5/WORKSPACE:31:14: in <toplevel>
  /home/wang/test_csh/protobuf-21.5/protobuf_deps.bzl:65:24: in protobuf_deps
  /home/wang/test_csh/protobuf-21.5/protobuf_deps.bzl:19:17: in _github_archive
Repository rule http_archive defined at:
  /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_wang/181be6b67ee4902db879f2b646f0f657/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:336:31: in <toplevel>
INFO: Repository rules_python instantiated at:
  /home/wang/test_csh/protobuf-21.5/WORKSPACE:31:14: in <toplevel>
  /home/wang/test_csh/protobuf-21.5/protobuf_deps.bzl:81:21: in protobuf_deps
Repository rule http_archive defined at:
  /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_wang/181be6b67ee4902db879f2b646f0f657/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:336:31: in <toplevel>
ERROR: Skipping ':protoc': error loading package '': in /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_wang/181be6b67ee4902db879f2b646f0f657/external/rules_pkg/mappings.bzl: Extension 'pkg/mappings.bzl' has errors
ERROR: error loading package '': in /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_wang/181be6b67ee4902db879f2b646f0f657/external/rules_pkg/mappings.bzl: Extension 'pkg/mappings.bzl' has errors
INFO: Elapsed time: 11.787s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (1 packages loaded)
```

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/README.md

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v21.5

Answer (score 3):

Happening to me too. Forget `bazel`, it's Google crapware from the depths of hell.* *Presumably* they know it sucks and breaks constantly so there happens to be a `cmake` solution in the archive:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
cmake -B build
sudo bash -c '(cd build; make install)'
```

Can't go wrong with that.

```
[  8%] Built target libprotobuf-lite
[ 29%] Built target libprotobuf
[ 50%] Built target libprotoc
[ 50%] Built target protoc
[ 50%] Built target gmock
[ 51%] Built target gmock_main
[ 54%] Built target protobuf-lite-test-common
[ 79%] Built target protobuf-test-common
[ 98%] Built target tests
[ 99%] Built target test_plugin
[100%] Built target lite-test
[100%] Built target lite-arena-test
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf-lite.a
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.a
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libprotoc.a
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/protoc-3.21.7.0
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/protoc
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/protoc-3.21.7.0" to "$ORIGIN/../lib"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/protobuf.pc
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/protobuf-lite.pc
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/any.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/any.pb.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/api.pb.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/arena.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/arena_impl.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/arenastring.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/arenaz_sampler.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/code_generator.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/command_line_interface.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/file.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_generator.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/generator.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/helpers.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/names.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_doc_comment.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_generator.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_names.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_options.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/importer.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/java/generator.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_generator.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/java/kotlin_generator.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/java/names.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/objectivec/objectivec_generator.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/objectivec/objectivec_helpers.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/parser.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/php/php_generator.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.pb.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/python/generator.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/python/pyi_generator.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/python/python_generator.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/ruby/ruby_generator.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/descriptor.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/descriptor_database.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/duration.pb.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/dynamic_message.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/empty.pb.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/endian.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/explicitly_constructed.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/extension_set.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/extension_set_inl.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/field_access_listener.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/field_mask.pb.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/generated_enum_reflection.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/generated_enum_util.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/generated_message_bases.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/generated_message_tctable_decl.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/generated_message_tctable_impl.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/generated_message_util.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/has_bits.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/implicit_weak_message.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/inlined_string_field.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/io/gzip_stream.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/io/io_win32.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/io/printer.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/io/strtod.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/io/tokenizer.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/map.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/map_entry.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/map_entry_lite.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/map_field.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/map_field_inl.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/map_field_lite.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/map_type_handler.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/message.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/message_lite.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/metadata.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/metadata_lite.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/parse_context.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/port.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/port_def.inc
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/port_undef.inc
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/reflection.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/reflection_ops.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/repeated_field.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/repeated_ptr_field.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/service.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/source_context.pb.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/struct.pb.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/stubs/bytestream.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/stubs/callback.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/stubs/casts.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/stubs/common.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/stubs/hash.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/stubs/logging.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/stubs/macros.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/stubs/map_util.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/stubs/mutex.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/stubs/once.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/stubs/platform_macros.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/stubs/port.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/stubs/status.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/stubs/stl_util.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/stubs/stringpiece.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/stubs/strutil.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/stubs/template_util.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/text_format.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/timestamp.pb.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/type.pb.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/unknown_field_set.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/util/delimited_message_util.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/util/field_comparator.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/util/field_mask_util.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/util/json_util.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/util/message_differencer.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/util/time_util.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/util/type_resolver.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/util/type_resolver_util.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/wire_format.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/wrappers.pb.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/any.proto
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/api.proto
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.proto
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/duration.proto
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/empty.proto
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/field_mask.proto
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/source_context.proto
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/struct.proto
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/type.proto
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/wrappers.proto
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/any.proto
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/api.proto
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.proto
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/duration.proto
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/empty.proto
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/field_mask.proto
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/source_context.proto
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/struct.proto
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/type.proto
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/wrappers.proto
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/protobuf/protobuf-targets.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/protobuf/protobuf-targets-noconfig.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/cmake/protobuf
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/protobuf/protobuf-options.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/protobuf/protobuf-config-version.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/protobuf/protobuf-module.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/protobuf/protobuf-config.cmake
```

* Just IMHO. YMMV.